make HUE(oozie) workflow to run on the last day of each month
When setting a schedule in HUE, how can I make it to run on the last day of the month? I'm trying to change the workflow that was running based on KST (Korea Standard Time) to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), so I need to reset the schedule times accordingly. As a result, I need to change the current schedule (e.g., 0 2,14 1 * *) that was set to run on the 1st of every month to run on the last day of each month instead. However, in HUE, when setting up an Oozie workflow, I cannot use the 'L' and '?' character in the crontab time expression. In this case, how can I make the workflow to run on the last day of each month?
